# git push heroku hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

Disclaimer: I am a noob.

I am learning ruby using the http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and until two days ago everything worked fine.

I am not sure exactly what went wrong but i am not able to push to heroku anymore, it starts fine but then hangs on the following line (These are the last lines on the console):

```
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
```

Facts:
Git remove -v works fine.
The app works fine on my computer.
My System : Latest Mac OS, RoR app.
My app is here: https://github.com/eladsof/sample_app

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have about 50MB of data files in your git repo.  Things seem to work when you remove them.

Try removing them with something like this (if you don't need 'em)

```
git rm ./db/pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001
git rm ./db/pg_xlog/000000010000000000000002
git rm ./db/pg_xlog/000000010000000000000003
git rm db/pg_clog/0000
git commit -m 'removing big files'
```

Then try pushing again.

(Assuming, of course, that you don't need them)

Comment: you beat me to it :) I was just testing that - getting rid of all the PG stuff in the DB folder fixes it, I've just deployed it successfully without it. Remove them, or use .slugignore so they don't end up being compiled into your Heroku slug.